# Find all files in the repo with the string "<<<<< HEAD"

Tags: git

My team recently switched to git, and in our learning process have managed to commit files in a "merge state", as in they unwittingly committed the file with both "<<<<< HEAD" and "<<<<< branch" string in the file.

I've run into a few of these through testing, but would like to find all files in the repo that have the string <<<<< HEAD in the file. Is there some bash incantation to provide a list of these files to fix?

Comment: git grep '<<<<< HEAD' might do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git grep -l '<<<<< HEAD'
```

This is equivalent to:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -l '<<<<< HEAD'
```

except it automatically ignores everything in the `.git` directory and only searches the working tree.

Answer (score 1):

```
git grep -l -E '^<<<<< HEAD|^<<<<< branch'
```

`-l` is to list files (instead) of lines, `-E` is to use extended regexes (i'm not sure | works without that).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the grep command on the root of your repo,

```
grep -nri '<<<<< HEAD'
```

this command will display the file and the line where it matches the pattern